# Resizing comment boxes on Excel(Apache POI) based on dynamic content from a database isn't working

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I'm attempting to create POI comments for certain cells on Excel Workbook of <org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel>. I'm able to view the comment box and the text is appearing, but the comment box size isn't fitting according to the text. Sometimes the text is cut off due to the small comment box, while other times the comment box is too large.

My goal is to ensure that all the text remains inside the comment box and that the comment box adjusts its size dynamically based on the text from the database not based on col1 and col2 value(from anchor). Help me to fix the anchor setting.

```
//i is an index of column cell where the comments needs to be added.
val anchor: ClientAnchor = drawing.createAnchor(3000, 0, 3000, 0, i, 2, (i+5), 5)
                anchor.anchorType = ClientAnchor.AnchorType.MOVE_DONT_RESIZE
                val comment = drawing.createCellComment(anchor)
                val string = XSSFRichTextString("$description")
                comment.string = string
                cell.setComment(comment)
```

I'm aware that the anchor is responsible for the comment box size. In this context, the values of Col1 is i here (the starting column of the comment box) and Col2 (the ending column of the comment box) value is i+5 these Col1 and Col2 determine the length of the comment box. In my case, the column cells don't have the same width, so the size of the comment box also varies.
e.

Comment: "My goal is to ensure that all the text remains inside the comment box and that the comment box adjusts its size dynamically based on the text from the database not based on col1 and col2 value(from anchor). ": Not possible. Microsoft Excel does not provide such setting. Or is your question about calculating `int dx2, int dy2, int col2, int row2` of the client anchor from given size of the comment-rectangle-shape? That would be possible.